# I changed 2-3 lines in my Visual Studio app and now version control is saying every file in the application is a new one?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Second time this has happened to me while using Visual Studio

Last time I restored from the origin to resolve.  Does anyone have any advice on another way to resolve this problem. Can I just go back one commit locally?

Note that I have been committing and pushing regularly so my local copy is just one small change behind the origin.

```
MacBook:Ja.git alan$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
    
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    
new file:   .gitignore
new file:   Ja.Android/Assets/AboutAssets.txt
new file:   Ja.Android/Assets/Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf

below this is a list of I think every single file in my app. 

MacBook:Ja.git alan$ git log --oneline -15
01c5848 (HEAD -> master) Clean up and remove unused properties
33e6677 (origin/master) Removed some unusued "using" and an u
```

[image]

Will my selecting the files and clicking "Revert” help solve this for me?

Comment: In visual studio you can undo change by right clicking the root node in changes screen.  What is most likely happening is that you are opening the files and VS is replacing linux line ending `\n` with windows `\r\n`.  This should be apparent you you use the compare (diff) option to see how your local copy differs from remote.

Comment: This isn't a new application and it’s something I have been working on (same computer) for a long time. It is showing all of the files as "new".  When I look at one of the files as an example it shows the original as having no lines and the new file as having 39 lines.

Comment: If it shows all files as new then must be issue with the history inside the `.git` folder.  When you type `git status` on the command line what does it show?  If it's the same as VS then it's your git history.  If VS is the only one saying its new then its a VS issue.

Comment: My question show the output of git status above.  Both git status and vs show every file as new but they are not new.

Comment: So its showing different files as being changed?

Comment: Both VS and git status are showing I think every file as being added.  Nothing is showing as changed. Please see the above git status.  There I show 3 files but all show as being added and that list is much longer

Comment: If git status shows every file as being added then visual studio is fine and not the issue.  Issue is that the file doesn't exist in your git history.  If git reports it as new so will VS.  How your git history got messed up is another issue.  I would try to see if you can re-create the issue in another project.